# Webpack is not displaying my img but only alt attribute text

Tags: javascript, html, image, webpack

as a recruitment task I have to copy layout using HTML/CSS and Vanilla JS. I've got a starter pack as a webpack bundle and according to recruiter documentation i have to just install all dependencies using npm install. After creating some layout in css i had to use img tag and here my problem start. First I had error that I'm missing img-loader, so I installed it. Now i can't see image but only alt attribute text.

this is my webpack.config.js for file-loader and img-loader:

```
{
        test: /\.(jp?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "img/[name].[ext]",
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "img-loader",
            options: {
              enabled: isProduction,
              gifscale: {
                interlaced: false,
              },
              mozjpeg: {
                progressive: true,
                arithmetic: false,
              },
              optipng: false,
              pngquant: {
                floyd: 0.5,
                speed: 2,
              },
              svgo: {
                plugins: [{ removeTitle: true }, { covertPathData: false }],
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```

here is file structure: [file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swi5P.png)

I tried installing all dependencies step by step, changing config and I searched internet across. Unfortunately i couldn't find any solution.

Comment: What do you get when you right-click on the alt-text, and inspect it? What's inside the `src` attribute?

Comment: @FiddlingAway `<img src="9974a4f97f05a522ba5a.JPG" alt="image">`

Comment: @FiddlingAway also i checked network tab and img is loaded correctly.

Comment: If that's the case, you seem to be missing the directory - it should have `img/` in front of the image name, shouldn't it? Also, is the image displayed when you hover over the contents of the `src` attribute?

Comment: @FiddlingAway it is showing only localhost url with image src. My original img tag looks like this `<img src="../img/_DSC5212.JPG" alt="image">` .

Comment: Alright, but what are the contents of the rendered HTML? Does you rendered HTML, the one displaying just the alt text, have a valid path to your image inside the `src`? Also, check if the browser with which you're viewing your page doesn't have disabled images. And check [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69698562/) as well.